Simulate js click event on Gtok HTML element
I'm trying to write JS test code for Gettr social site & I have problem with simulating a JS click() event on Gettr GTok video player
Sample link (take any)
https://gettr.com/gtok/p3e65qa96a2
I'm trying to click on the arrow down element
It can be found using this query
document.querySelector("a[href*='\/gtok\/']:nth-child(2)")
But click(); doesn't work
document.querySelector("a[href*='\/gtok\/']:nth-child(2)").click()
nothing happens.
I've tried to trigger mouse events:

function simulateMouseClick(targetNode) {
    function triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
        targetNode.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
    ["mouseover", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"].forEach(function(eventType) { 
        triggerMouseEvent(targetNode, eventType);
    });
}

simulateMouseClick(document.querySelector("a[href*='\/gtok\/']:nth-child(2)"))


Doesn't work too...
The app is based on React, I never had any issue with writing tests for React apps but this one just refuses to be clicked on :D
I suspected it might check for 'isTrusted' in onclick event, but I couldn't find any references to this string in JS files...
I've tried to fire 'keydown' event on this item
function fireDownKey(el)
{
    var key = 40;
    if(document.createEventObject)
    {
        var eventObj = document.createEventObject();
        eventObj.keyCode = key;
        el.fireEvent("onkeydown", eventObj);   
    }else if(document.createEvent)
    {
        var eventObj = document.createEvent("Events");
        eventObj.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
        eventObj.which = key;
        el.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
    }
} 

fireDownKey(document.querySelector("a[href*='\/gtok\/']:nth-child(2)"))

Still nothing! Stubborn element to click on...
